# Routing of an activity task to preferably a specific worker in the SWF fleet

Tags: amazon-swf

Considering the [fileprocessing](https://github.com/aws/aws-swf-flow-library/tree/master/src/samples/AwsFlowFramework/src/com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/flow/examples/fileprocessing) sample which executes download activity on any host from the pool, then converts the file and uploads the result on the same host as the first one, is there a way to route an activity task to preferably (not always) a specific worker in the SWF fleet based upon the worker's availability, reason is that the worker should not be overloaded with tasks which might affect the latency.

Comment: One possible option is by leveraging timeout parameters in com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.ActivitySchedulingOptions. For instance,  1) Start with specifying a specific activity task-list for the execution of activity task  X with an acceptable scheduleToStartTimeoutSeconds value, so that this task is routed to a specific worker 2) If there is a time-out, then specify the default activity task-list for the execution of activity task X, so that this task is routed to any worker.

Answer (score 0):

There are two use cases for not overloading host with tasks. The first is when a host just needs to limit a number of parallel activities running on it. It is done by setting the ActivityWorker.setTaskExecutorThreadPoolSize property.

The second is when a host needs to limit number of sequences of activities running on it. For example as in fileprocessing example limiting number of files to be processed at the same time. The solution is to use a special semaphore like activity that runs for the duration of the whole sequence. Here is the outline of the implementation:

1. Hosts listen for "semaphore" activity on a special common task list using a separate activity worker.
2. The number of parallel activities on this worker is limited through setTaskExecutorThreadPoolSize.
3. Once the "semaphore" activity starts executing on a host it sends a signal to its workflow with a host specific task list. Then it just keeps periodically heartbeating to SWF.
4. All other activities from the given workflow are dispatched to the host specific task list received through the signal sent by the "semaphore" activity.
5. After the last host specific activity is done the "semaphore" activity is cancelled.
6. The semaphore activity learns about cancellation on the next heartbeat. Then it rethrows cancellation exception which completes it with the worker and releases a place in the task executor thread pool.

A variation is to not use the cancellation but notify the semaphore activity in process by the last activity in a sequence.